# Consume a service jar by spring boot

Tags: spring, rest, jar

I am working on the web service project by Spring Boot, services exist in a jar,
My question is how to consume these services?
Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

(according to your tags, you've developed REST services.)

Postman is a great tool (great GUI with many functionalities) to test your REST services.

It's available as [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) or as [stand alone app](https://www.getpostman.com/).

Comment: Thank you for your reputation,My problem how to scan services in the jar , what the jar is a project that contains the following layer:entity,dao,service

Comment: I do not understand, how did you expose your services ? Through RestController ? In that case, you can check logs at startup, all services exposed are listed :
`2017-07-12 08:25:08.833  INFO 11788 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/simple],methods=[GET]}" onto public ...`